# Downside of using IServiceScopeFactory to created Scoped DB Contexts for multi-threading

Tags: multithreading, asp.net-core, asynchronous, dbcontext

In our application architecture, we use EF as an ORM to our database. When making use of asynchronous programming we came into an issue where a DBContext cannot be used by multiple threads at one time when injected through a constructor.

To circumvent this, we make use of the IServiceScopeFactory and created a scoped context of our DBContext when needed through a using () statement. This allows us to run DB calls through EF concurrently.

For tasks that do not run concurrently, we inject our DBContext in through our constructor and use that.

What is the immediate downside (if any) of using IServiceScopeFactory when programming asynchronous tasks using EF?

The method that we use can be found here: [IServiceScopeFactory and EF](https://entityframeworkcore.com/knowledge-base/55777022/ef-core-dbcontext-in-a-multithreaded-api-application)

Thanks

Comment: Connection starving and concurrency problem are the the two easiest to see... and, personally, I think only them cause enough headache...

Comment: @GordonKhanhNg. thanks for the response. How would you go about handling multiple threads when making use of EF to contact the database without using IServiceScopeFactory?

Comment: I think the best practice would be use a `dbContext` instance per processing flow, and that's why we used `IServiceScopeFactory`. If not, have some kind of lock object or semaphore would restrict threads from use the dbContext at a specific time, but that logic would much more complex. And I used `IServiceScopeFactory` for them if i ever needed too